# show IP BGP summary size in bytes per column

Tags: bgp

Given the image below:

[image]
It says that it only has 1 peer and it is using 4568 bytes of memory. Does anybody knows how?

how many bytes are each column on the table? As far as I know neighbor is 4 bytes, V is 1 byte and AS is 2 Bytes, what about the rest?

In other words, how does the router came to the conclusion that one peer is using 4568 bytes of memory?

thanks.

Comment: BGP has a lot of information per prefix. BGP has attributes for each prefix, and the size of those can vary per prefix. You should look at _[RFC 4271, A Border Gateway Protocol 4 (BGP-4)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4271)_. Even things like the AS numbers can be different sizes. The original AS numbers were 16 bits, but the new AS numbers are 32 bits.

Comment: This will depend on the amount of attributes, size and so on. But basically it is vendor wise, i.e how many bytes are assigned per prefix, attributes, next hops.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: No one answered and it really doesn't matter anymore. I do not know the protocol in this kind of situation

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, many internal software data structures have a constant overhead which does not depend on how many items are stored in the data structure; in other words, whether there is one peer or 32 peers, the overhead is the same. A better way to check the actual memory consumption per peer is to configure another peer, and measure the difference between the newly reported memory usage and 4568. Then configure a third and see if the consumption goes up exactly by that number.

Secondly, the output of a "show" command only displays items of interest to the network operator. There may be many bytes which have to be stored per peer but not displayed in the "show" command output (for example, a data pointer to some other data structure in the memory, a pointer to the next peer, or whatever). Without reading the source code it is impossible to say.

Comment: I did and it seems to be consistent every peer that I add is 4568. For two peers: 2 x 4568 Bytes = 9136 Bytes
For three peers: 3 x 4568 Bytes = 13,704 Bytes
For four peers: 4 x 4568 Bytes = 18,272 Bytes